# Bezier Path - calculate X,Z by giving T from more than 3 points

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, bezier

Ok, here is exactly what i am trying to do.

- When i move my mouse over the surface, i collect the CVector2 points into std::vector
- Those points shall create a Bezier Path for my object to follow it

At this point i have positions stored and i need to

- Calculate the X,Z on this bezier path later on, so that my object will follow this path.

Now here is what i have:

- Store all the points as the std::vector
- And when engine ticks the object i :

> // Return position on Bezier at current fTime
>
> CVector3 CBezierPath::Calculate(const float& fTime)  {  CVector3
>   vPosition;  ... return vPosition;           }

Yes, how do i calculate the position in **fTime** on a Bezier Path made from **N** number of points?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok found solution,

Knowing that i have x number of waypoints, i generate Bezier curves where number of curves is equal to:

iCurves = iWaypointsCount / 3

Now after i calculate T for current curve i just skip to another curve and restart calculating to from 0 to 1.

```
   // If we are not finished on this curve
    if(m_fBezierT < 1.0)
    {
        m_vPosition = m_BezierPath.CalculateBezierPoint(m_iCurrentCurve, m_fBezierT);

        m_fBezierT += 0.3f * fDelta;
    }
    // Finished, go next curve
    else
    {
        // No more curves
        if(m_iCurrentCurve+1 >= m_BezierPath.GetCurveCount())
        {
            m_fBezierT = 1.0f;
        }
        // Switch to next Curve
        else
        {
            m_fBezierT = 0.0f;
            m_iCurrentCurve++;
        }
    }
```